# how can i save data to mockapi serve?

Tags: json, reactjs, api

i learn ReactJS, And i have homework task. I need create chat. And i need use mockApi server. I chose Mockoon. Server works fine and i can see my data at React app. But how can i save my data to Api?

this is my axios request:

```
axios.post(`http://localhost:9000/user/`, { user })
  .then(res => {
     console.log(res);
  })
```

as i understand {user} should send to api my data. 
But if i see at console i can see this:

[here what i see at console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfYgS.png)

my data at config: and not at data: and this only at browser. If i reload page al reseted.

So here question, can i save my data from input to mockapi serve?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with [mockswitch](https://mockswitch.com) - it supports various connectors example local drive (saves to file system ), github (user defined github account - great if you are doing, mongo etc.

Their docs is available here https://mockswitch.com/docs/#storage